Не работает mock-server MSW и RTK хук висит в состоянии pending
Пишу тест, который будет проверять работу хука из Redux RTK Query. Пытался сделать mock сервер используя MSW библиотеку, но по какой то причине, сервер не работает, а хук при запросе висит в состоянии pending.
Создал обработчик, который будет возвращать моковые данные
// handlers.ts
import { http, HttpResponse } from 'msw';


export const handlers = [
  http.get('/api/0.3/dict/weather/precipitation', () => {
    return HttpResponse.json({
      Mix: 'Смешанные осадки',
      NoPrecipitation: 'Нет осадков',
      Rain: 'Дождь',
      Snow: 'Снег',
    }, { status: 200 });
  }),
];


Создал моковый сервер
// mock-server.ts
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';

import { handlers } from './handlers';


export const server = setupServer(...handlers);


Подключил для тестов
//setupTests.ts
import { server } from './mock-server';


beforeAll(() => server.listen());
beforeEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());


Написал тест
// weatherApi.test.tsx
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from 'history';
import { getStore } from 'src/store';
import { useGetDictPrecipitationsQuery } from 'src/api/rest';


const history: History = createBrowserHistory();

const store = getStore(history);

function Wrapper({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}

describe('useGetDictPrecipitationsQuery hook test', () => {
  const mockData = {
    Mix: 'Смешанные осадки',
    NoPrecipitation: 'Нет осадков',
    Rain: 'Дождь',
    Snow: 'Снег',
  };
  const endpointName = 'getDictPrecipitations';

  it('render hook', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useGetDictPrecipitationsQuery(), { wrapper: Wrapper });

    expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
      status: 'pending',
      endpointName,
      isLoading: true,
      isSuccess: false,
      isError: false,
      isFetching: true,
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isSuccess).toBe(true));
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
      status: 'fulfilled',
      endpointName,
      data: mockData,
      isLoading: false,
      isSuccess: true,
      isError: false,
      currentData: mockData,
      isFetching: false,
    });
  });
});


И тест падает на строке с проверкой isSuccess, потому что сервак ни ошибки, ни результат не возвращает, вечно в pending статусе и isFetching: true
Пробовал тестировать хук с использованием fetchMock, все работает, а вот с MSW нет
